# Proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1{A_n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} { \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k) } =0$.

Tags: probability, limits, expectation, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers and  $\{A_n\}$ be
a non-decreasing sequence of positive numbers, tending to infinity. Let $\{X_n\}$  be a integrable,
centered sequence of i.i.d. random variables. Put $Y_n=X_n \mathbf{1}_{ \{ |X_n|\le A_n/|a_n| \} } $. We have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E} (Y_n)=0$ and $$\sup\limits_{n\ge 1} {\dfrac{\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n {|a_k|}}{A_n}} <\infty.$$
Proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}   \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} { \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k)  } =0$.

In my opinion, since $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E} (Y_n) =0 $ so for all  $\varepsilon>0$, exists $N\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that    $| \mathbb{E} (Y_n) |\le \varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Hence
    \begin{align*}
 \left| \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} { \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k)  } \right|  
 %& \le \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} {\left| \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k) \right| } 
 &\le \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}   {\left| \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k) \right| } +  \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{n}  |a_k|. {\left| \mathbb{E} ( Y_k) \right| } \\
 & \le \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}  {\left| \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k) \right| } +  \varepsilon.\dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=N}^{n}  |a_k| \\
& \le \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}  {\left| \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k) \right| } +  \varepsilon.M,
 \end{align*}
with $M=\sup\limits_{n\ge 1} {\dfrac{\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n {|a_k|}}{A_n}}$.
Take $n\to\infty$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$ we obtain $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}   \dfrac{1}{A_n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} { \mathbb{E} (a_k Y_k)  } =0$.

Is my above proof right or wrong? Can I replace condition: $\sup\limits_{n\ge 1} {\dfrac{\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n {|a_k|}}{A_n}} <\infty$ by $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\dfrac{\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n {|a_k|}}{A_n}} <\infty$?

Comment: Proof seems fine. For the last suggestion, rather write $\lim sup$ in the end. The (essentially) same proof still works.

Comment: Thank you. I can replace $\sup$ by $\limsup$ in the end, right?

Comment: Logically fine. You may (?) add in the end why the first terms tends to zero (although it is fairly obvious). For the limsup case just notice that for any $M$ greater than lim sup, the relevant bound is correct for $n$ large enough.

Comment: To assumtion, since $A_n/|a_n|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \infty$ (I didn't mention above), hence we have
 \begin{align*}
 \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E} (Y_n) &= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {\mathbb{E} {[X_1 \mathbf{1}_{\{|X_1|\le A_n/|a_n|\}}}]} 
 = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {\displaystyle\int_{\{|x|\le A_n/|a_n|\}  } {x{\rm d} F_1 (x)}} \\
 &=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} {\displaystyle\int_{\frac{-A_n}{|a_n|}}^{\frac{A_n}{|a_n|}} {x{\rm d} F_1 (x)}} 
 = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {x{\rm d} F_1 (x)} =0.
 \end{align*}

Comment: Ok, perhaps correct the statement in the question then? But your calculations look fine. Suggest adding  'dominated convergence' for the argument in your comment.